# HTAccess giving 404s in wamp

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I have installed WAMP and enabled the mod_rewrite module.

I am not used to developing on a windows machine, any recommendations?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  //Rewrites if the directory doesn't exist
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  //Rewrites if the file doesn't exist

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]  // Change this to suit your needs

</IfModule>
```

localWebsite.ht.local, loads correctly.

localWebsite.ht.local/index.php, loads correctly.

localWebsite.ht.local/myQuery, does not load correctly, it gives a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules look fine and assuming you've got the htaccess file in the correct directory (your domain's document root) then the only thing wrong that I see is that you're checking for the wrong module.

Because of a peculiarity in the way apache checks for modules, you need to check for the `.c` file, not the shared object file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Then ensure that you have the rewrite module loaded.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I should have realised that Windows uses the C libraries whereas nix uses shared objects!

Comment: @HarryTorry It is the same as on nix. When loading modules using `LoadModule`, you refer to the shared object (.so) but when checking to see if a module is loaded, you check the .c file because it's possible modules are compiled into apache and not dynamically loaded (depending on the build, the distribution, etc. many modules can optionally be compiled into the executable)